# Installing a Hydro package in Indigo

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ethzasl-icp-mapping, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am quite new to ROS. I have the following package:
[ethzasl_icp_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_icp_mapping)
which is available for hydro but not for indigo. How can I install this package with indigo?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236222/installing-a-hydro-package-in-indigo/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a indigo-devel version available on the [github](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping/tree/indigo_devel), have you tried using this ?

Just `git clone` it in you catkin workspace and then use `git checkout` to switch to the hydro-devel branch

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-06-07**:
Thanks for the reply. So, in simple terms, I need to get the indigo devel branch and get it to my catkin workspace folder and execute catkin_make?
I don't understand why we need to switch to hydro-devel branch.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2016-06-07**:
indigo develstand for indigo-development and is the branch that the developer tested on indigo. If you don't switch to it, it might work, but if it doesn't, then it's not a bug. It's the wrong branch. Otherwise, in simple term, yes you're right :)

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-06-08**:
Thank You so much. But just to be clear the last part of the answer should be `git checkout` to switch to the the indigo-devel branch, right?

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2016-06-08**:
it's `git checkout` and then the name of branch. If you press tab, it should auto-complete

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-06-09**:
Thank you for the help.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2016-06-13**:
If it answered your problem, could you mark it has accepted so future people with the same question will know that there is an answer :) ?

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-06-14**:
Yes. I will. But I would like to mention that I haven't actually tried this one.